# Не работают заголовочные файлы с шаблонами c++

Tags: c++

Когда подключаю заголовочный файл, который включает в себя функции с шаблонами, компилятор выдает ошибку. .cpp файл я заранее подключил в проект, с обычными функциями все работает. Что я делаю не так?
Ошибка: Ошибка  LNK2019 ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ "void __cdecl print(int)" (??$print@H@@YAXH@Z) в функции _main. _forTests   C:\Important\Studying\my-programs\C++ Programs\C++ Programs_forTests_forTests.obj

print.h

```
#pragma once

#include <iostream>

void a();

template <typename T>
void print(T t);

template<typename T, typename... Args>
void print(T t, Args... args);
```

print.cpp

```
#include "print.h"

void a() {
    std::cout << 'a' << std::endl;
}

template <typename T>
void print(T t)
{
    std::cout << t << std::endl;
}

template<typename T, typename... Args>
void print(T t, Args... args) // Если более 1 элемента
{
    std::cout << t;
    print(args...);
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "print.h"

int main() {
    print(2);
}
```

Comment: Делаете стандартную ошибку - определение шаблона не в заголовочном файле... Заголовочные как раз работают :) Интереса ради - поставьте себя на место компилятора - почему при компиляции print.cpp он должен инстанцировать print именно для `int`?

Comment: Можно сказать компилятору инстанцировать этот шаблон для инта. но с typename... Args уже не факт что прокатит. Можно из print.cpp в print.hpp перенести все шаблонные функции и в конце  print.h поставить #include "print.hpp"